# Django-storages to serve different urls (HTTP or HTTPS) to different users?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, boto, django-storage

Right now my site is widely used behind one corporate network. For whatever reason, they refuse to connect to the recent HTTPS version of my site and I can't back into why. I've settled on the idea that they have issues in their backend.

Until I figure a workaround, I thought I would take them back the non-ssl version of my site.  I'm not sure what the best design pattern here is with django-storages. Right now in my settings file I have:

```
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'website.s3pipeline.S3PipelineStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'media.website.com'
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN =  "media.website.com"
```

I'm not sure the best design pattern on how to read if the user is coming from http or https and then serve the secure URLs or not.

If I wasn't using pipeline and storages, I could directly choose to load in different .css or .js files on the template site, but that would feel to hacky here.

Any ideas?